# RemoveClass / Addclass

Tags: html, edit, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

It's my first post in this community :D
I need help with .removeclass and .addclass function :(

My idea it's a button that when you click it, a div change the height and width.
As this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
     <div id="clas4">
        <button onclick="_edit()">Edit</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
function _cambio(){
    $('#content div').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('clas4').addClass('min');
    });
};
```

**CSS**

```
#clas4 { width: 60%; height: 40%; border: 1px solid black; z-index:5; position:absolute;}
.min { width: 10%; height: 10%; border: 1px solid black; background-color:blue;}
```

---

Well, when I click the button, my div changes the backgorun colour to blue, but ignore the height and width options =/ someone know why??

Thanks so much ^^

Answer (score 0):

set your div class to be clas4 as well. You should be already aware about _edit() vs _cambio() names...

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="clas4" class="clas4">
        <button onclick="_edit()">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the style:

.clas4 { width: 60%; height: 40%; border: 1px solid black; z-index:5; position:absolute;}

Answer (score 0):

Delete ---->> function _cambio(){

```
<div id="content">
     <div class="clas4">
        <button class="click">Edit</button>
     </div>
</div>

$('.click').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('clas4').addClass('min');
});


.clas4 { width: 60%; height: 40%; border: 1px solid black; z-index:5; position:absolute;}
.min { width: 10%; height: 10%; border: 1px solid black; background-color:blue;}
```

----->>>};

Comment: Hi! I don't know if I edited bad the code but this didn't works :( But thanks for your help ^^

Comment: @user3424570, You need jquery to use this. That's the reason it didn't work I guess.